# Настройка отступов в vim: смешанный стиль.

Tags: отступы, vim

Как настроить vim так, чтобы:

1. Отступы от начала строки делались символами `'\t'`
2. Все отступы (с помощью клавиши `TAB`) после делались пробелами.

Первого легко достичь с помощью команды `set noexpandtab`. Как добиться второго пункта?

Например:

```
somecode: [
    one:   1
    two:   long_call(1, 2, 'option')
]
```

Все расположенное от начала строки и до `one:` и `two:` должно быть заполнено `'\t'`. А всё между `one:` и `1` — пробелами.

Comment: Встречал плагин в сети, реализующий такой функционал. Заставить работать не удалось :(

Answer (score 1):

Для начала: здесь написано, чем различаются [alignment и indentation](http://habrahabr.ru/post/118208/). Твой второй вопрос и есть - как настроить в ВИМ alignment.

Во второй статье [на Wikia](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Indent_with_tabs,_align_with_spaces) в самом последнем разделе **Continuation lines** предлагается использовать плагин [Super retab](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/VimTip1592)